# How to get value of variable from function?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

*I am trying to get value from a function and store it in a variable but I am getting null.*

```
String imgUrl='';
getUrlSP()  async  {
SharedPreference preferences 
 =await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String Url = 
 preferences.getString('imageUrl').toString();
setState(() {
  imgUrl=Url;
});
  print('Printing Image Url inside function:${imgUrl}');
}
```

*outside function*

```
print('Image Url :${imgUrl}');
```

The results I got in the terminal are

I/flutter (32164): Image Url :

I/flutter (32164): Image Url Stored in Prefs
is:https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/veeluser.appspot.com/o/User%20Images%2FdCP6WEESxfYNDIMqtt57n2BsxYf1?alt=media&token=d864a502-209f-4262-9860-b9d4d3222091

_As from the above results that I got in terminal I am not getting the value of imageUrl outside the function._As I am new to flutter so if there is an error or there is any other solution please share it.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected. since your `getUrlSP` function is declared as `async`, you'll need to use `await` when calling it to ensure it completes (and sets `imgUrl`) before the rest of your code runs.

So:

```
await getUrlSP();
print('Image Url :${imgUrl}');
```

I recommend taking the Flutter codelab [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 0):

should be used `setString()` to add a string value to the shared preferences .

Example :

```
String imgUrl='';
getUrlSP() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('imageUrl', imgUrl);
print('==> ${imgUrl} <==');
}
```

Comment: Everything is working fine except I am not getting value in variable imgUrl to use it outside function.